# wordpress output statuscode 200, content: service unavailable

Tags: wordpress

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEc5v.png)

It seems wordpress is outputting this 'Service Unavailable', but this site works fine before, and no files are modified. 
I have searched code files with grep, only two places output 'Service Unavailable', but with different status code, any body can help?

Answer (score 0):

`Service Unavailable` is usually a result of a mysql issue/warning. Try restarting the mysql service.

Also, adding `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to your `wp-config.php` will allow you to see the actual error message. https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but as to my situation, the response is 200 ok, I have opened the DEBUG mode, but failed to see any problems,